# MYSQL Update PHP File Stop Updating

Tags: php, mysqli

I have updated my code to include prepared as suggested below. However, I am getting "0 records UPDATED successfully". Once again the database is not being updated.

My new code is

```
 try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
  $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "UPDATE mailinglist ". "SET optout = '$optout'". 
  "WHERE email = '$email'" ;

   // Prepare statement
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

   // execute the query
  $stmt->execute();

  // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
  echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
   }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
   }

 $conn = null;
 ?>
```

Has anyone experienced this before and if so, does anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Note: your code is open to SQL injections since you just put whatever the user sends you into the SQL string. Start using parameters immediately in all SQL queries. Otherwise “on” isn’t really a valid value for a varchar(1) but is for varchar(5)...

Comment: change to $_GET where $_POST and try it

Comment: @ Sami Kuhmonen I have not learned that yet but as soon as I do I will make the change. Thank you for letting me of my security issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql = "UPDATE mailinglist SET optout = ".$optout." WHERE email = ".$email;
```

Hello,

Just try out this.
I have made some changes i.n above line, just replace it with your line.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, however, by making this change I get "Error updating record:"